# How can I use Google Places Search Box without the Map?

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I want to add Google Places Search Box (AKA Google Places Autocomplete) to my website, But I want It to appear without the Map. All I need is the autocomplete search box.

This is the documentation link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

I looked for a solution but could not find one. (all i found was an address search without a map)

This is my code in full:
(I did get an API KEY and plant it on the bottom of the code and it works great, but it shows with the map).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #description {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
          }

          #infowindow-content .title {
            font-weight: bold;
          }

          #infowindow-content {
            display: none;
          }

          #map #infowindow-content {
            display: inline;
          }

          .pac-card {
            margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
          }

          #pac-container {
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            margin-right: 12px;
          }

          .pac-controls {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 11px;
          }

          .pac-controls label {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;
          }

          #pac-input {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 400px;
          }

          #pac-input:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
          }

          #title {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 500;
            padding: 6px 12px;
          }
          #target {
            width: 345px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
          // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
          // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

          // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
          // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
          // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

          function initAutocomplete() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
              zoom: 13,
              mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });

            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
              searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });

            var markers = [];
            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
            // more details for that place.
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
              var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

              if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
              }

              // Clear out the old markers.
              markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
              });
              markers = [];

              // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              places.forEach(function(place) {
                if (!place.geometry) {
                  console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                  return;
                }
                var icon = {
                  url: place.icon,
                  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                // Create a marker for each place.
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  icon: icon,
                  title: place.name,
                  position: place.geometry.location
                }));

                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                  // Only geocodes have viewport.
                  bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
              });
              map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
          }

        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
             async defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: anyone knows ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Here is the answer:

1. create an API key:
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete#try-it-yourself
2. Use ajax to manipulate this link (the "**input**" is what you will look for, the "**location**" is your latitude and longtitude - you should get it from the user's ip)
   ***https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=pasta&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY***

   remember to change the YOUR_API_KEY to your API kEY

This is where I got it from:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?csw=1#requirements

- you can not use the link that I've posted in my Original question to do that
- you must not charge fees for your service if you are going to use it.
  you can read about the Licence Requirements here:
  https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?csw=1#section_9_1

Answer (score 1):

You have to use place autocomplete API for it. its allow you for 1000 request per hour and if you enable billing then you can have 150000 request per day  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY

you can set place preference for your search
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&region=AU
in this above link it return search related to AU first